# What should be encoding of the text message body to be send using smtp?

Tags: encoding, notifications, smtp, sms

The smtp mail server is adding extra periods to the url links in the text message body. Is it something related to the encoding of the text body ?

Comment: Could you include the example?

Comment: The message body sent to the mail server is 
New Notification: "Upcoming 9/25 Schedule".      http://test.app.com/default.aspx?t=99999&aid=99999&nb=1

But message received is :-
New Notification: "Upcoming 9/25 Schedule".      http://test.app..com/default.aspx?t=99999&aid=99999&nb=1

Notice the extra period between app.com